# RMI; JRMP connection error; Caused by connection reset

Tags: rmi, jrmp

I get the following Exception and I can't figure out why that is happening.

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at Daemon$ShutDownProcedure.run(Daemon.java:126)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

I have a Daemon class that is responsible to start up a Server in a separate JVM. In that Daemon I have a ShutDownHook that calls a method on the remote server object which, on the server, starts a shutdown procedure.

The Daemon itself is also an exported RMI object but on a different port so that I can start a server remotely.
That means the Daemon has created a Registry listening on port 1099 and the Server has a Registry listening on post 1098.

Now I also have a "ClientGui" that can shutdown a server and restart it. It can access both the Daemon to launch a server and the Server to shut it down.

Daemon class:

```
//.....
private Daemon(String[] args){
    try {
        this.reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        this.stub = (DaemonRemote) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 1099);
        this.reg.rebind(DaemonRemote.class.getName(), this.stub);   
        this.arguments = args;
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new ShutDownProcedure());          
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

//....
public static void main(String[] args){             

  String initialargs = Arrays.stream(args).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
  String[] command = new String[] {"java", "-Xmx4g","-cp", System.getProperty("java.class.path", "."), Server.class.getName(),initialargs};

  try {
    p = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO().redirectErrorStream(true).start();          
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();  
    }       
    if(daemon == null)
        daemon = new Daemon(args);
}
//....
private class ShutDownProcedure extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run(){      

        if(p.isAlive()){
          try {
            Registry serverreg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(null, 1098);
            ServerRemote serverrmi = (ServerRemote) serverreg.lookup(ServerRemote.class.getName()); //this is the line where the exception occurs...
            serverrmi.killServer();
          } catch (IOException | NotBoundException | InterruptedException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

From my ClientGui I access the remote Server object in exactly the same way as from the Daemon and can also call the killServer() method without a problem. But when I hit CTRL+C to initiate the ShutDownHook from the Daemon, the mentioned exception is being thrown when trying to lookup the exported Server object.

The websearch didn't give me any ideas on how to solve this... but maybe I am looking in the wrong direction...

Any help is greatly appreciated and I thank anyone in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, hitting "CTRL+C" during the batch-job (the Daemon is being started from cmd executing a bat-file) shuts down both JVM's and thus the registry created in the server JVM shuts down as well.

To resolve my issue I just added a ShutDownHook to the server which will initiate its own ShutDownProcedure. Unfortunately I haven't found a good way to start a completely separate "unhidden" cmd-window and start another jar-application using ProcessBuilder yet.

Thanks to EJP's advice, I removed the Registry creation part from the code and start it from the batch-file.

Answer (score 1):

This is all pointless. You're shutting down the entire JVM. That will take the Registry you created in your JVM with it, along with all the bindings. In fact obviously the Registry has already exited during your `lookup()` call.

Just remove your shutdown hook.

In any case if you are the remote object yourself, you don't need to lookup the Registry to find yourself. All you needed was to unbind and then unexport yourself. But you don't even need that.

Comment: I do get that shutting down the JVM kills the Registry but in this case I don't lookup itself but the exported server object. The server runs in a separate JVM launched by the Daemon. I think the problem actually is that my Daemon gets started from "cmd.exe" and the server started from inside the Daemon also uses the same window as the Daemon. So hitting "CTRL+C" shuts down both JVM's. Since the server doesn't have any hooks I guess that server registry is down before the Daemon can access it. And since getRegistry doesn't check if it exists would explain the exception at that line.Thanks :)

Comment: Ah OK missed that. I would run `Server` in the same JVM, which would eliminate all that malarkey. If you must do it in two JVMs, you should lookup in the shutdown hook via `this.reg`, not via `LocateRegistry.getRegistry()`. The reason is that `this.reg` is the actual Registry implementation object, not a stub, so even if it has been unexported or its I/O threads have exited the lookup will still work.

Comment: I see your point @EJP but the Server must have its own JVM for coming changes. Using `this.reg` I would ref. the Daemon reg for JVM(1). The idea is to get the reg of the server in JVM(2), lookup the server object and initiate shutdown, immediately return and let Daemon finish. I see that I could register the server object to the Daemon reg so I would only have to deal with one. But in case I lose the Daemon hook on the server I will have a zombie process. I do deal with that when starting up a new server though. Using a server reg I keep having control over the "zombie-server" from my GUI. :)

Comment: Hang on. You don't need two Registries. The one in JVM 1 on port 1099 is sufficient. If you're trying to be robust, start the `rmiregistry` command line utility. It never crashes. Or use Activation.